# FacebookGraphAPIError: (#210) This call requires a Page access token

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, passport.js, passport-facebook

I am using Passport-Facebook strategy for authentication. Please find the code below:

```
new FacebookStrategy(
      {
        clientID: authConfig.facebookAuth.clientID,
        clientSecret: authConfig.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: authConfig.facebookAuth.callbackURL,
        profileURL: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me",
        authorizationURL: "https://www.facebook.com/v2.10/dialog/oauth",
        tokenURL: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/oauth/access_token",
        profileFields: ["email", "profile_pic", "gender"]
      },
      function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
```

This is giving me the following error:

```
FacebookGraphAPIError: (#210) This call requires a Page access token.
```

How do I pass the page access token? Or is this related to something else?

Comment: What API call are you actually trying to make when this occurs? The above seems to be configuration only?

Comment: This is what they say in the Passport-Facebook documentation: `Passport strategy for authenticating with Facebook using the OAuth 2.0 API.`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have found the problem. This had nothing to do with the Access token. Some of my profileFields parameters were invalid. The modified, working code is given below:

```
new FacebookStrategy(
      {
        clientID: authConfig.facebookAuth.clientID,
        clientSecret: authConfig.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: authConfig.facebookAuth.callbackURL,
        profileFields: [
          "id",
          "displayName",
          "email",
          "gender",
          "picture.type(large)"
        ]
      }
```

Comment: thanks mate! not sure why on API 4.0 its still a bug