# This call requires a Page access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to login with facebook, which is done. I need to get user info like name, email, hometown, location, gender, profile_pic. But i can only get username of the logged in user. I also added fields parameter to api. You can see that in below code.

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
 var accessToken;
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
    appId      : 'App Id',
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v3.1'
   });

   FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   

   function getuserProfile() {
    FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,birthday,gender,hometown,location,profile_pic', {access_token : accessToken }, function (response){
      console.log(response);
    });
 }  

FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    getuserProfile();
  } else {
    console.log('not connected');
  }
}, {scope: 'email'});  
};

(function(d, s, id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Answer (score 9):

Some fields can be specified wrong and that is why `Facebook API` is giving such an error even when everything else seems fine. For instance `profile_pic` field can cause such an error which should be something like `picture.type(large)`. See also: [FacebookGraphAPIError: (#210) This call requires a Page access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433359/facebookgraphapierror-210-this-call-requires-a-page-access-token)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you get asked for the email permission in the login popup. Also, you need to ask for additional permissions with the scope parameter, not just email. For example, `user_birthday` to get the birthday of users. Right now you are only asking for the email permission.

Example:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    getuserProfile();
  } else {
    console.log('not connected');
  }
}, {scope: 'email,user_birthday,...'});  
};
```

Reference for permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/

Comment: Thanks, But i am beginner. Can you please edit my code for practical example.

Comment: And as you answered, "You are only asking for email permissions now". In the response i am only getting username and Id.

Comment: you really just need to add additional permissions to the scope parameter, that´s all. about the email: emails are not required on facebook, so you may not get an email for every account. again, make sure you actually get asked for the email permission in the login popup.

Comment: i have updated your code with an example for the birthday permission.

Comment: Thanks, can you please tell me how many parameters i can pass to scope like email, user_birthday?. for ex, if i want to get user location then what should i need to write in scope.

Comment: as many as you want. i have added a link to the docs where you can see all the permissions.

Comment: I made my app live. But till it is giving me only name and Id.

Comment: you do know about app review, right? you can´t just make it live and it will work, you have to go through a review process with those additional permissions. before making it live, make sure it works with a user with a role in the app. for those it will work without review. and again: make sure you get asked for the permissions. DO you get asked for them in the login popup?

Comment: Yes, when user log in, It gives "This app requires your email, birthdate, location". But in doesn't giving me location.

Comment: BTW, Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: before, you said "only name and id", now you say "it does not return the location"...so, the birthday works? are you sure there IS a location in the user profile?